# additionalproperties aws GeneratePreSignedURL

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use AmazonS3 client to GeneratePreSignedURL, however I need to change the filename by changing ContentDisposition in the ResponseHeaderOverrides.  I do not wish to use GetPresignedURL in this case.

```
var responseHeaderOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides()
        {
            ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=" + filename
        };

_awsClient.GeneratePreSignedURL(_bucketName, path, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), null, **additionalProperties**);
```

There is a parameter called additionalProperties that is IDictionary<string, object> that I think can be used to send the ResposneHeaderOverrides, however I am unsure how to use this.

How can I map additionalProperties parameter for GeneratePreSignedUrl with the responseHeaderOverrides value?